# Remove Duplicate value from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON object

```
var data = [
{totalTime: 67, phoneNo: "400-234-090"}, 
{totalTime: 301, phoneNo: "701-080-080"}, 
{totalTime: 300, phoneNo: "400-234-090"}
]
```

I want to remove duplicate object. Please guide. Output should be as below one

```
var data = [{totalTime: 301, phoneNo: "701-080-080"}]
```

Comment: @Daniel This is not a duplicate of that. OP wants to **remove** all the duplicates from the array, not just keep all the unique ones.

Comment: Example which you have mentioned is not removing duplicate record. It is just removing occurrence.

I need unique records.

Comment: @Andy did any of the answers bellow solve your problem? If so you should mark the answer. It helps others etc.

Answer (score 2):

For a solution with low complexity, I'd first make an object that counts the occurences of each `phoneNo`, and then `filter` the input by the count of each object's number being 1:

```js
var data = [
  {totalTime: 67, phoneNo: "400-234-090"}, 
  {totalTime: 301, phoneNo: "701-080-080"}, 
  {totalTime: 300, phoneNo: "400-234-090"}
];
const phoneCounts = data.reduce((a, { phoneNo }) => {
  a[phoneNo] = (a[phoneNo] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(
  data.filter(({ phoneNo }) => phoneCounts[phoneNo] === 1)
);
```

Comment: @Andy When an answer solves your problem, you can consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you please guide me how to accept the answer

Comment: You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): `click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use two filters such that, we will only select objects that are just single entry in the array

```js
const data = [
  {totalTime: 67, phoneNo: "400-234-090"}, 
  {totalTime: 301, phoneNo: "701-080-080"}, 
  {totalTime: 300, phoneNo: "400-234-090"}
]

const newData = data.filter(outer => 
  data.filter(inner => 
    outer.phoneNo === inner.phoneNo
  ).length === 1
)

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: This has `O(N^2)` complexity... not important in small datasets, but probably not preferable regardless

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes O(n^2) indeed. But has less space complexity as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option (1 reduce, 1 filter and spread):

```js
var data = [
{totalTime: 67, phoneNo: "400-234-090"}, 
{totalTime: 301, phoneNo: "701-080-080"}, 
{totalTime: 300, phoneNo: "400-234-090"}
];

console.log(data.reduce((x, { phoneNo }, i, a) => 
  a.filter((y) => 
 y.phoneNo === phoneNo).length > 1 ? x : [...x, a[i]], []))
```